# Regex with exactly one space and special characters

Tags: regex

Unfortunately I found that the existing examples are confusing and not similar enough to what I am trying to achieve. I need a regular expression to find occurencies of strings like

```
=> Test[a]
```

where between the special character `>` and `Test` there is exactly one space. The word `Test` can be replaced by any alphabetic string (`=> Apple[b]` is another example). I have worked out a regex for all except the first part with the block `=>`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How about... `"=> "`? What is exactly the trouble here with the space?

Comment: *'I have worked out a regex'* Care to show that to us?

Comment: Thanks everyone and sorry. I thought I needed to escape special characters and do something about spaces. I am using this expression in notepad++

Comment: .(=>) [a-zA-Z]+\[a\]\.

Comment: it now works :-)

Comment: You are not clear regarding what you want to capture, and how. `(=>\s[^ ]+)` capture all the string, `(=>\s[^ ]+)\[[a-zA-Z]\]` capture only => Test , `=>\s([^ ]+)\[([a-zA-Z])\]` capture Test and a divided, `(?<==>\s)([^ ]+)\[([a-zA-Z])\]` is like previous one, but match without =>\s, and so on.  If you specify better what you have to do it's easier to answer

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find this expression

```
.(=>) [a-zA-Z]+\[a\]\.
```

and it works! Thanks everyone.

Comment: It's not working, according to https://regex101.com/ .  Maybe you means `(=>) [a-zA-Z]+\[a\]`, that's not working with => Apple[b]?

Answer (score -2):

Try use this regex:

```
=> \S+
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8mpVbT/1)

Comment: This is also matching `=> $*%!:`